# Largest normal soluble subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group and suppose that $S(G)$$\ne$$1$ where $S(G)$ denotes the largest normal soluble subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $N$ is non-trivial normal soluble subgroup $N$$\ne$$1$,  $N$$\vartriangleleft$ $G$ such that the quotient group $G$/$N$ has no nontrivial abelian normal subgroups. Can I conclude that $S(G)$$=$$N$ ? Is it correct? Thank you very much to everyone for the help!

Comment: Yes, you can. Where to Stack ? it is quite elementary. Just Check the image of $S(G)$.

Comment: Also there is no need to assume that $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

Take $\;G=S_3\;,\;\;N:=A_3$ . Then $\;S(G)=G\;$ and $\;G/N\cong C_3\;$ has no non-trivial subgroups whatsoever.

Comment: What about $G/N$ itself ?

Comment: @mesel It is written there "no **nontrivial** normal..." I tried to go *exactly* by what the OP wrote.

Comment: @DonAntonio, thank you. But with the condition that $G/N$ is non-abelian, my conclusion is correct?

Comment: Trivial subgroup of $G/N$ is only identity subgroup. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Sibilla Not sure. I'll have to check, though mesel probably was thinking something of the like as he commented below your question that "Yes, you can."  Maybe he can post an answer with this assumption

Comment: @mesel I think you are. As fas as I know, both the identity subgroup *and the whole group* are called "trivial" ....perhaps someone else has a different understanding of this, though.

Comment: Trivial groups, https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Trivial_subgroup   
 but maybe nontrivial normal means ...

Comment: @mesel In the same part site:  "The term, when referred to "G has no nontrivial proper subgroups" refers to the only subgroups of G being the trivial group {e} and the group G itself." This is what I understood

Comment: @DonAntonio , thank you!